# $B_{\mathcal{l_2}}$ convex in $\mathcal{l_2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

In the space $\mathcal{l_2}=\{x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty:\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}x_n^2<\infty\}$, I am trying to prove that $B_{\mathcal{l_2}}=\{x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty:\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}x_n^2\leq1\}$ is convex.

To do so, I am trying to prove that if $x,y\in B_{\mathcal{l_2}}$, that is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2\leq1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n^2\leq1$, and $\lambda\in [0,1]$ , then $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\in B_{\mathcal{l_2}}$. I need to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((1-\lambda)x_n+\lambda y_n)^2\leq1 $. What I have done is this:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((1-\lambda)x_n+\lambda y_n)^2\leq1 = (1-\lambda)^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 + \lambda^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n^2+2(1-\lambda)\lambda \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n \leq (1-\lambda)^21 + \lambda^2 1+(1-\lambda)\lambda (\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n^2) \leq (1-\lambda)^2 + \lambda^2 +2(1-\lambda)\lambda = (1-\lambda+\lambda)^2=1$,

where I have used that $x_ny_n \leq \frac{1}{2}(x_n^2+y_n^2)$.

However I am not sure this proof is correct, because there is case that worries me: could it be possible that $(1-\lambda)<0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$ is $-\infty$ or a negative number that makes that the sum of everything is greater than 1?

It would be very helpful if anyone could point out how to prove this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, then $1 - \lambda < 0$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum x_n^{2} \leq 1$ if and only if $\|(x_n)\| \leq 1$ where $\|(x_n)\|=\sqrt {\sum x_n^{2}}$. In any normed linear space $\{x: \|x|| \leq 1\}$ is a convex set since $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\| \leq \lambda \|x\|+(1-\lambda) \|y\|$.